# Running foo.com and foo.com/blog from different hosts using proxy, loadbalancing or other network magic

Tags: networking, proxy, load-balancing

Say I have foo.com - and I want to create a blog in foo.com/blog, but I want to run it on WordPress, which is not possible to install on the same server.

Networking is not my strong suit, so forgive my ignorance when I ask this slightly vague question...:

Is there a way to put a... load-balancer, proxy, something... out front that serves the content for foo.com/blog from fooblog.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache on foo.com, you can use [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) to set up a reverse proxy to reroute /blog to another server:

```
ProxyPass "/blog" "http://backend.foo.com/blog"
ProxyPassReverse "/blog" "http://backend.foo.com/blog"
```

Be careful to make sure you do not enable the forward proxy (`ProxyRequests` should be off) at the same time, because then the server can be used to access any host as a regular proxy.

If the current front-end is not running Apache, you could run Apache in front of it and set up proxying to both back-ends.